# How to go to a new view from within an ion-slide-box - Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic project where I implement ion-slide-box. This ion-slide-box has a total of 12 slides.

My question is how to achieve going to a new view when the user is on the last slide (the 12th slide). Now I have basically done this by creating one empty slide (after the 12the slide). So when I slide the last slide you will see and empty slide before the ion-slide-box transition to the new view.

So basically I am looking for a solution to slide from the last slide to the new view without creating an empty slide.

To illustrate this beter see the short vid I made:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlTo6MjU04Y

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

There is an event when you start a slide change

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
  console.log('Slide change is beginning');
});
```

You can probably use it to implement your needs.